# QGIS - Linking origin and destination points with nearby routes (vectors)

Tags: merge, qgis

**Context**

- Dataset A contains the origin and destination coordinates of trips made by car in CSV format (n=~1M).
- Dataset B contains public transport routes for the same area in vector format (GPKG with ~600 features).

**Objectives**
I want to estimates how many of the trips in Dataset A could have been made using public transport. I consider that a trip could easily have been made using public transport if it originates and ends within 400 meters of a public transport route.

**Initial Approach**
My initial thinking was to import Dataset A in QGIS, use the "Join attributes by nearest" tool, and export the joined layer back to CSV for further processing in Stata.

**Problems faced**

1. My first problem is that Dataset A is too big, which makes QGIS slow down or crash.
2. I tried splitting Dataset A in 100 parts, but I haven't found a way to batch import and project them (which is needed to calculate a 400-meter buffer).
3. After the join, the Joined layer is even bigger, since each observation in Dataset is joined to an average of 150 features from Dataset B (I never quite get there because the program crashes or freezes before).
4. The "Join attributes by nearest" tool creates one record/line per match. Instead, it would be more manageable for me if the output dataset stored each in matched public transport route as a distinct column/variable (the number of lines in the dataset would remain unchanged, only the number of columns would increase).

**Questions**

1. Does my approach make sense? Is there a much more efficient way to do this that I haven't considered?
2. Any ideas on how to solve the problems listed above would be greatly appreciated.

I am not familiar with Python, but willing to learn the basics if that's the solution. For now, I work mostly with Stata and know how to use QGIS.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Smoon